# Center for Regular Polygon Code

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that follows certain criteria regarding Regular Polygons and finding the perimeter and area of the polygon. I have to write three different classes Point2D, RegularPolygon, and Driver. I can get all of the necessary criteria to work fine except for when it comes to using the instance variable center to have the center coordinates x and y. There are two things that use the center in the RegularPolygon code and I can't get them to work. I need to have a Point2D instance variable center that stores the x  and y    coordinates of the polygon’s  center,  with  default  values  0 for  both  the  x    and y    components  of  the  Point2D object. I also need to have a constructor that creates a regular polygon with the specified number of sides, length of side, and a Point2D object that represents the center of the polygon, in that order. I also need to have A method public String toString()that returns a String representation of the polygon  containing  the  number  of  sides,  side  length  and  center  coordinates for this polygon. Call the toString()method on the Point2Dcenter as part of this method. However, when I go to call the toString method in Point2D it comes up as an error. If anyone can help me figure out why I can't get it to work in my code I would greatly appreciate it.

//Code for Point2D

```
 public class Point2D
 {
//Instance Variables
private int x;
private int y;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Point2D, this will initialize
 * the instance variables
 */
public Point2D(int xVariable, int yVariable)
{
    //Initializes Instance Variables
    x = xVariable;
    y = yVariable;
}

//Accessor Method for X variable
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

//Accessor Method for X variable
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

//ToString Method
public String toString() {
    return "<" + x + "," + y + ">";
}

//Method that tests if the values of x and y are equal
public boolean equal(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Point2D) {
        Point2D c = (Point2D)o;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

//Code for RegularPolygon

```
  public class RegularPolygon
  {
// instance variables
private int n; //Number of sides
private double side; //Length of sides
private double x; //Value of X-Coordinate
private double y; //Value of y-Coordinate
private double center; 

/**
 * No argument constuctor that creates a regular polygon with 
 * default values
 */
public RegularPolygon()
{
    //Intilializes Instance Variables
    n=3;
    side =1;
    x=0;
    y=0;

}

/** 
 * Constructor that creates a regular polygon with a specific number
 * of sides, length of side, and a Point2D object that represents the
 * center of the polygon.
 */
public RegularPolygon(int n, double side, double x, double y) {
    this.n = n;
    this.side= side;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

//Mututator Methods
public void setN(int nValue) {
    n = nValue;
}
public void setSide(double sideValue) {
    side = sideValue;
}
public void setX(double xValue) {
    x = xValue;
}
public void setY(double yValue) {
    y = yValue;
}

//Accessor Methods
public int getN() {
    return n;
}
public double getSide() {
    return side;
}
public double getX() {
    return x;
}
public double getY() {
    return y;
}

//Calculates the Perimeter of the regular polygon
public double getPerimeter() {
    return n * side;
}

//Calculates the Area of the regular polygon
public double getArea() {
    double area = (n * (Math.pow(side,2))) / (4 * (Math.tan(Math.PI/n)));
    return area;
}

//To String Method
public String toString() {
    return "Number of sides: " + n + ", Side Length: " + side + ", Center Coordinates: "+Point2D.toString(x,y);
}
```

}

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: The error is in the toString method in the RegularPolygon code. It says that Point2D.toString(x,y) doesn't work, but I'm not sure why it won't work

Comment: What is the exact stackTrace?

Answer (score 0):

Your toString method in Point2D does not take variables as parameters, yet you call it from RegularPolygon with parameters at the end. But the way you called Point2D uses its toString method like a static method, even though it's not. So you either have to instantiate a Point2D, or make Point2D's toString method static. But the problem with this is that then you have to make your x and y in Point2D static as well. Another problem with making your toString() method static is that you can't override Object's toString method. So I recommend that you do the following:

```
    public String toString() {
        return "Number of sides: " + n + ", Side Length: " + side + ", Center Coordinates: "+new Point2D((int)x, (int)y).toString();
    }
```

Comment: If I were to create a private Point2D instance variable would I have to call it that or could I call it something different? Because I need to have a Point2D instance variable named center that stores the x and y coordinates of the polygon’s center, with default values 0 for both the x and y components of the Point2D object within my RegularPolygon code. I also need to have a constructor that creates a regular polygon with the specified number of sides, length of side, and a Point2D object that represents the center of the polygon, in that order. I will take any suggestions you have. Thanks

Comment: No, the point is that you don't need to make a private Point2D instance variable. The point is that you can instantiate a Point2D variable with x and y within the same line of code as the return statement, and then get the toString of that instance. Scroll to the right of the code I posted; if you replace your RegularPolygon's toString() method with this one, it should work now.